# Is there any way to instrument System.Reflection.Emit?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

I'm having some serious trouble with a compiler that does its code generation with the classes found in `System.Reflection.Emit`.  It takes code that should be perfectly valid, and that passes all the compiler's internal checks, and tries to codegen it, but `TypeBuilder.CreateType()` throws the following completely unhelpful exception:

> System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

The problem lies somewhere in the way it's transforming generators into state machines in a specific edge case, but if I take the post-transformation AST, turn it back to source code, and feed it into the compiler as-is, everything builds successfully and runs as expected, which means something very strange is going on.

The problem is, `System.Reflection.Emit` is a black box.  It would be very nice if I could instrument it somehow and have it produce a step-by-step log of exactly what it's doing, so I can diff the working and non-working versions and see where the problem lies.  I tried doing this manually, tracing through the codegen phase's execution step by step in the debugger and taking notes of what got called where, turning it into a script, but it took several days and I must have missed something somewhere, because I'm getting the same error even though it was the "working" version I was tracing through.

Does anyone know of a way to log `System.Reflection.Emit` so I can get a good idea of what's really going on here?

Comment: Are you just looking to do that with `TypeBuilder`? If that is the case, you could create a factory and a mock/wrapper class that implements the interface `System.Runtime.InteropServices._TypeBuilder`. Then in your implementation code you can have your debug statements or logging code. You may need to include `System.Type` as a factory as well.

Comment: @gmiley There are a lot of classes involved in the process.  Besides the builder for types, there are individual builders for fields, properties, methods, method parameters, generic arguments, locals, constructors (apparently these aren't method-like enough to be handled by `MethodBuilder`), labels, and IL generation within a method (or constructor).  And that's just off the top of my head; there are probably a few more...

Comment: Have you thought about possibly [downloading the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/ilgenerator.cs,9a7e4a4d758eaf0f), adding your own logging, and trying it out? Looking through the source it doesn't seem that there is much you can attach in the way of instrumentation, but it may be another option. (Yes, this may be a lot of work to wedge in, mocking up internal classes, etc)

Comment: Have you looked at `TypeBuilder` in ILSpy at all to try to walk through what is happening based off of your known inputs? `CreateType` calls `CreateTypeNoLock` after it performs a lock. There is a lot going on in that method.

Comment: @RonBeyer: I thought of that, but considering how a lot of the relevant code is implemented in native code in mscorlib as QCalls, attempting to build my own version feels like one of those "that way lies madness" traps.

Comment: @MasonWheeler one other thing, the compiler you are speaking of, are you certain it is compiling to the proper platform (32 vs 64 bit)?

Comment: @gmiley I'm quite certain it's compiling to 32-bit, as expected.

Comment: And is the application that loads that DLL compiled to 32 as well? Since you said you can take the output and compile it yourself, it leads me to believe it is an issue with the compiler or its settings instead. And it would be better to actually solve your problem, rather than have you write a ton of code to do something ultimately unnecessary.

Comment: @gmiley: This is taking place inside the compiler, before any application is loading the DLL.

Comment: What is the compiler? Is it a custom compiler? What architecture is the PC that the compiler runs on?

Comment: Can you save the bad assembly to disk? You can then inspect and PEVerify it.

Comment: @gmiley: I deliberately didn't put details like that into the question because it would lead into side-discussions and digressions off onto stuff that I already have figured out.

Comment: @usr: That's a good question; I hadn't thought of that.  Is it valid to save the assembly without calling `CreateType()` on all the `TypeBuilder`s first?  That would make my task a lot easier, as I could open both versions up in `ildasm` and compare them side-by-side.  (Asking here instead of trying it out because I'm at work and the project in question is at home.)

Comment: The only other thing I could suggest is that you go through the list of possible causes in MSDN for that exception and see if any of them match your scenario: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I don't know, but I would think so. It would be strange API design to simply drop such types on the floor.

Comment: `BadImageFormatException` is usually caused by loading an assembly, I don't think I've ever seen `CreateType()` throw it. So: 1. Just to make absolutely certain: are you sure it's `CreateType()` that's throwing it? 2. Is the type you're creating referencing other assemblies? Could that be the cause of the issue? 3. What is the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @svick: 1) Yes, I'm sure. 2) It is, but it's not likely to be the cause of the issue because I'm able to compile the pre-transformed code, which references the same external assemblies, correctly. 3) The top of the stack trace is in `TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock`, which isn't particularly helpful.  I think it's really happening inside native code somewhere.

Comment: @usr Unfortunately, I just tested it and `AssemblyBuilder.Save()` throws if you haven't created all the types defined in the assembly.  That was a very good idea, though.  It's too bad it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Why can't you actually reproduce the issue? Is this non-deterministic? Is the compiler threaded?

Comment: @usr It's completely deterministic; it's just that even a very simple reproduction of the compiler issue in question involves a lot of complexity at the IL generation level, and somewhere along the line I'm missing some details.  I'd like to have an automated way to keep track of what's going on.